# Sorting Tables Using ListObject Column References

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to sort two tables in two different sheets and getting no where fast. I've taken a look at examples on stack and they seem to be using workarounds to refer to static ranges as apposed to referencing the actual table and column.

I'm trying to Filter Audit_MA_Main table Column "6 Week Due Date" / Column H on the sheet in Chronological order Oldest to newest 
&
trying to sort Audit_Inflight table Column "Status" / Column B Alphabetically A-Z A ... descending down to Z.

Below is what I've got so far could any one suggest a way of how to finish?.

```
Sub SortByDate()
' Tables to filter Audit_MA_Main - 6 Week Due Date  Column H  Audit_MA_Main[6 Week Due Date] Oldest to Newest
'                   Audit_Inflight - Status Column B  Audit_Inflight[Status] - A-Z
Dim ASortRange As Range, MASortRange As Range
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook, HomeWorksheet As Worksheet, MAInflightSheet As Worksheet, AuditInflightSheet As Worksheet

Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set HomeWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
Set AuditInflightSheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Audit_InFlight")
Set MAInflightSheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("MA_Inflight")

Dim AuditStatusLO As ListObject
Set AuditStatusLO = AuditInflightSheet.ListObjects("Audit_Inflight")
    AuditStatusLO.ListColumns(3).Select        ' Select the Status Column
    AuditStatusLO.ListColumns(3).Sort SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I played around with the Macro Recorder ..... as I should have done firstly but this might help some one else. Solution to my problem is below:

```
Sub SortByDate()
' Tables to filter Audit_MA_Main - 6 Week Due Date  Column H  Audit_MA_Main[6 Week Due Date] Oldest to Newest
'                   Audit_Inflight - Status Column B  Audit_Inflight[Status] - A-Z
Dim ASortRange As Range, MASortRange As Range
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook, HomeWorksheet As Worksheet, MAInflightSheet As Worksheet, AuditInflightSheet As Worksheet

Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set HomeWorksheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
Set AuditInflightSheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Audit_InFlight")
Set MAInflightSheet = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("MA_Inflight")

Dim AuditStatusLO As ListObject
Set AuditStatusLO = AuditInflightSheet.ListObjects("Audit_Inflight")
    AuditStatusLO.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    AuditStatusLO.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Audit_Inflight[[#All],[Status]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With AuditStatusLO.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```